# AWS: elastic IP disassociated without API call

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

For what reason would an elastic IP disassociate from a running Instance without any API calls being made?

I am experiencing an odd situation where my running AWS instance is being disassociated from the elastic IP address without any action on my part.

I tried allocating a new address and associating the instance with the new Elastic IP, but the same situation occurs where the IP address is "automatically" disassociated from the instance.

The only thing I haven't tried is stopping and restarting the instance (to move it to new hardware) but I'd rather not lose my internal IP address.

Has anyone else experience such an issue?

Comment: If you post this question with the instance id to the EC2 forum, somebody from Amazon might take a look.  They seem to have logs of everything that happens inside EC2. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=30

Comment: Some interesting EIP dissociations kept happening to me when attaching to an ENI associated with a Lambda instance. Looks like it can just happen if you leave it idle for too long. https://repost.aws/questions/QUv6u-_MpvSZueahD0UbPYkA/elastic-ip-dissociated-from-elastic-network-interface-after-lack-of-use

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there is currently an issue with Elastic IP address that requires an Instance stop/start in order to ensure that the Elastic IP address "sticks"

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=84952&tstart=0

Answer (score 1):

We've noticed this happening to our instances also... I think the problem is a result of the internal IP changing because they are dynamic. When the internal IP changes, the elastic IP drops and you have to associate it again. It's happened to us during a reboot we initiated and it happened on an amazon reboot d